# How to implement inmobi ads in Corona SDK?

Tags: android, coronasdk, ads, inmobi

My question is not actually how to implement.

So my question is i have developed a physic game that have 20 levels and menus scenes and where should i implement the inmobi ads?

Should i just implement when the game starts (in the menu scene) or should i implenment in every levels and scenes?

All the scene are in defferent .lua classes.

Thanks in Advance!

My question is not actually how to implement.

So my question is i have developed a physic game that have 20 levels and menus scenes and where should i implement the inmobi ads?

Should i just implement when the game starts (in the menu scene) or should i implenment in every levels and scenes?

All the scene are in defferent .lua classes.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

In your main.lua use `ads.init()` to get the ads:

```
ads.init( "iads", "myAppId", adListener )
```

and then use `ads.show()` in all the scenes you want to show ads:

```
ads.show( "banner", { x=0, y=0 } )
```

then if you want to hide ads in some scene use:

```
ads.hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just call the `adBanner` code once in your app to display an ad in every scene.

My suggestion:

1. Here, just create a flag when you enter into the menu page first time.
2. Call the inmobi adbanner code.
3. Reset the flag (it will prevent you from calling the `adView` many in every time you entering into your menu page).

And you can show or hide the ad in any page you desire by the method that `vovahost` specified in the post.

Answer (score 0):

For inmobi, you will need to setup your account with them where you will get an App ID number.  Then you can use code like this:

```
local ads = require "ads"

local function adListener( event )
    if event.isError then
        -- Failed to receive an ad.
    end
end

ads.init( "inmobi", "myAppId", adListener )
ads.show( "banner320x48", { x=0, y=100, interval=60, testMode=false } )
```

See http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/ads/init.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some kind of "level complete" screen, I would put the ads there. I would think putting them on the actual levels and menus would be too annoying to the user.